# Call javascript parameterized Function

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, button

I have one Input button control i want to call javascript function with parameter.
parameter is object of my Asp.Net repeater.

here is my Button

```
<input id="btnAddNew" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" type="button" value="Add More" onclick="AddFileUpload(<%# Eval("PrimaryID")%>)" />
```

and JavaScript Function is like this

```
function AddFileUpload(PrimaryID) {

            document.getElementById('<%= hdnField.ClientID %>').setAttribute('value', PrimaryID);

        }
```

Comment: What is the problem/question ?

Comment: thank you for response...problem is

onclick="AddFileUpload(<%# Eval("PrimaryID")%>)" gives Some syntax Error

Comment: could you please post the client side code (compiled code from you browser inspector)? and what you expect from `Eval("PrimaryID")` to return as value?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your <%# Eval("PrimaryID")%> is returning non-numeric value so this would generate the syntax error.

replace

```
onclick="AddFileUpload(<%# Eval("PrimaryID")%>)"
```

with

```
onclick="AddFileUpload('<%# Eval("PrimaryID")%>')"
```

I hope this will work fine if not then post your error here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<input id="btnAddNew" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" type="button" value="Add More" onclick="AddFileUpload('<%# Eval(\'PrimaryID\')%>')">
```

Hope it works for you..